# Change Version in iTunes Connect - App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to change version of app.
Right now 1.0 version is live and I uploaded build to TestFlight with new version 2.0
but not submitted to App Store .

But **I want to submit 1.2 version in place of 2.0** so it is possible to upload 1.2 version to store?

When I am trying to upload new build with version 1.2, getting error like

App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.2] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [2.0]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring%22)

I know new build version should be higher than old version but any possibility then le me know.

Please help me out if it is possible

Thanks

Comment: "it is possible to upload 1.2 version to store?"  No, I don't think so.  I made a similar mistake before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the version that gets displayed to the end user, you can always change that directly in App Store Connect. The "display version" is independent from version code attached to each build.

[image]

Once you have a higher version used for your builds there is no way to "decrease it" again.